# Discordbotを特定のチャンネルのみでだけ動かせるようにしたい。

Tags: python, discord

作成したbotをサーバーに入れたのですが全てのチャンネルで反応して動いてしまうので、特定のチャンネルのみで動かせるようにしたいです！

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import os
import subprocess
import ffmpeg
from voice_generator import creat_WAV

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
voice_client = None



@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')


@client.command()
async def join(ctx):
    print('#voicechannelを取得')
    vc = ctx.author.voice.channel
    print('#voicechannelに接続')
    await vc.connect()

@client.command()
async def bye(ctx):
    print('#切断')
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    msgclient = message.guild.voice_client
    if message.content.startswith('.'):
        pass

    else:
        if message.guild.voice_client:
            print(message.content)
            creat_WAV(message.content)
            source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("output.wav")
            message.guild.voice_client.play(source)
        else:
            pass
    await client.process_commands(message)


client.run("トークン")
```

Answer (score 1):

on_messageに条件をつけることで特定のチャンネルだけにできます。

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
```

を

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id != チャンネルID:
        return
```

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id not in [チャンネルID, チャンネルID2]:
        return
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！試してみたら無事できました！！